# Permutation and combination of distinct Rings vs distinct balls

Tags: permutations, combinations

Sir/Mam,
I had read a question that goes as follows-"In how many ways can 4 rings be worn in index, ring and middle finger if there is no restriction of the number of rings to be worn on any finger? " The answer was -" each of the 4 rings could be worn in three ways, hence answer is 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 =3^4 ways".
Now the second question is " five balls of different colours are to be placed in three different boxes such that any box contains at least 1 ball. What is the maximum number of different ways in which this can be done ? " And the answer was 150.
Now why can't I interpret the second question as " each of the five different balls can choose any of the three boxes" and give an answer as
3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 =3^5 ?
Please explain this in detail with simple terms , so that a student like me who is weak in mathematics can understand this...
Thank you

Comment: Where are you ensuring that each box contains at least one ball? $3^5$ includes also, for example, all balls in one box.

Comment: Sir, if suppose the question does not mention about ensuring the "one ball" condition, is the above solution valid?

Comment: Yes. Then it's the same question: put $n$ objects into $k$ boxes without restrictions. Each object has $k$ options so in total we have $k^n$ options. BTW, I don't like the wording of the original question, because fingers are not boxes. 2 rings on the same finger can be worn in 2 different manners where the answer implies that they are the same.

Comment: Ok sir... Yes you are right about the wordings... It is a MBA entrance test question.. thank you sir, I am glad that you helped.. now I understand it...